# Active tab text not changing with page load at startup time

Tags: javascript, css, html

My tab text color not changed with page load. Background color change with load for default active tab, but text remain with same color.

```
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #ffffff;
    float: center;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #74cfff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ededed;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #74CFFF;

}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;   
}
```

Here is my java-script code.

```
  <script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

    // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

here is HTML code. Tab1 is by default selectd tab. so It's color and text should be change. but not working as I want. selected tab back color should be '#75cfff' and font color '#ffffff'. If I select other tab than same first tab text should change to white and back color to '#75cfff'.

```
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')" id="defaultOpen" >tab1 <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">tab2 <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">tab3 <img src="assets/images/infoico.png" width="20" height="20"></a></li>
                    </ul>

<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
    <div style="border-bottom: thin solid #f1f1f1;" >
    <p> tab1</p>
    </div>                              
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
    <div style="border-bottom: thin solid #f1f1f1;" >
    <p> tab2</p>
    </div>                              
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
    <div style="border-bottom: thin solid #f1f1f1;" >
    <p> tab3</p>
    </div>                              
</div>
```

Comment: Your code gives errors for me.  `document.getElementById(cityName).style.display`, but the citynames don't actually have id tab1,tab2,tab3

Comment: I think you just need to make a division with `class=""tabcontent"` and pass this three tab name as id

Comment: I already have it in my code, I forget to post here.

Comment: I update my question with tabe content.

Comment: That’s a simply specificity problem. `ul.tab li a` has much higher specificity than just `.active` - so the color definition of the first one “wins.” Make your second selector at least as specific as the first one.

Comment: I made a seperate `.active` class so Its works now thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the css.
If you inspect the state of the html elements on startup you notice

`<a class="tablinks active" id="tab1" style="display: block;" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')" href="javascript:void(0)">tab1 <img width="20" height="20" src="assets/images/infoico.png"></a>`

that the active tab doesn't get styled correctly.

`ul.tab li a` sets the color back to the same blue, so the text isn't readable.
After you click the element in the script, the link loses focus again, so it's the `.active` css that sets the text. But since the css rule `.active` has a lower weight than the rule `ul.tab li a`, you'll never get the color unless the element stays focussed.

I would remove the color from `ul.tab li a` and use a seperate class for it, so that you don't have issues with css weights. You could add !important instead, but that's a quicker but worse solution.

Comment: thanks, there is no problem with worse solution but Its worked fine.